# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am calling a service class: "CustomUserService" from MyController.

```
 public class MyController{


  private final CustomUserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public MyController(
      CustomUserService userService) {
      this.userService = userService;
  }
```

The userService is as follows:

```
    @Service 
public class CustomUserService implements ICustomUserService { 
           @Autowired   public CustomUserService(SpringAuthClientCustom authClient){
              this.authClient = authClient;   } }
```

My authClient is:

```
@Service
public class SpringAuthClientCustom extends AbstractCustomSpringClient  {
}
```

which extends: `public abstract class AbstractCustomSpringClient  {}`

**AbstractCustomSpringClient** is from the external jar and I have added that to my dependency.

Now, I am getting

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'SpringAuthClientCustom' defined in file
> [C:\Users..\SpringAuthClientCustom.class]: Post-processing of merged
> bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.**..AbstractCustomSpringClient  ] from ClassLoader
> [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]

I have added scanBasePackages in the BootAplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = { ""com.externalJar.client.*"}
```

Still, spring is not able to resolve the dependency. What could be the possible reason? Is it because of the AbstractCustomSpringClient  class outside my project ( in the jar) and not defined as @Service?

Thanks

Comment: scanBasePackages for external package is not needed. This is most likely due to dependency not found. Add the full stacktrace and how you have included the external jar in your classpath to the question.